# Issues while running Django web app and wordpress on the same apache server

Tags: python, django, wordpress, apache, mod-wsgi

I am working on building a wordpress blog for my website. I am deploying the whole application on an AWS instance. I want to see my website when i am redirecting to the PublicDNS of my instance and when i use PublicDNS/blog i want to see my blog. I have my web app developed using python.
I am trying to setup a reverse proxy to achieve this.

Also, I followed the link below to set up mod_wsgi

https://www.sitepoint.com/deploying-a-django-app-with-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04/

what I did was this

sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin ubuntu@localhost
#       DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/myproject
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIScriptAlias /mypath/ /home/ec2-user/myproject/apache/wsgi.py
<Directory "/home/ec2-user/myproject/apache/">
  Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin root@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  # Servers to proxy the connection, or
  # List of application servers Usage
  ProxyPass / http://54.67.96.30:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://54.67.96.30:8080/
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Was not succesful tho. Please help me with this. Also guide me if i need to make any other changes to make my Django and wordpress run on the same apache server

Here is my error.log

```
ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-X-XX:/var/log/apache2$ cat error.log
[Sun Nov 06 07:58:56.224050 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1063] AH00163:                                         Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured   -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Nov 06 07:58:56.224115 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1063] AH00094: Command     line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Nov 06 11:54:32.059667 2016] [:error] [pid 15819] [client  189.219.102.10:34144] script '/var/www/html/command.php' not found or unable to  stat
[Sun Nov 06 11:54:32.489969 2016] [core:error] [pid 15818] [client   189.219.102.10:34149] AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET   /../../../../../../../mnt/mtd/qt HTTP/1.0
[Sun Nov 06 15:54:03.556565 2016] [:error] [pid 15819] [client  91.196.50.33:35265] script '/var/www/html/testproxy.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Nov 07 04:58:22.325454 2016] [:error] [pid 15818] [client   185.25.148.240:52671] script '/var/www/html/testproxy.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Nov 07 16:34:19.809578 2016] [core:error] [pid 15813] [client 220.202.123.178:2844] AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET HTTP/1.1 HTTP/1.1
[Mon Nov 07 17:52:01.884887 2016] [:error] [pid 15819] [client 91.196.50.33:55532] script '/var/www/html/testproxy.php' not found or unable to stat
```

Comment: what do the logs say?

Comment: Please give a proper error description!

Comment: You can't have multiple VirtualHost for same port with none of them having ServerName set. Apache will route all requests to the first VirtualHost as it will not be able to apply name based virtual host matching using the hostname in the URL, as it doesn't know which VirtualHost is for which host name.

Comment: For details on mixing PHP and mod_wsgi on the same Apache go read: http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/hosting-php-web-applications-in.html

Comment: Thanks so much for your response @GrahamDumpleton That was really helpful. I am still working on it. I have updated my recent apache2 error.log in the question. Please help

Comment: thank you for your response @WissamYoussef Please find my error.log i have update in the question. Please help

Comment: thank you for your response @KlausD. Please find my error.log i have update in the question. Please help